# Styling(coloring) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am comparing two dataframes based on unique id and showing the result like below in excel-

[image]

I am using the highlight_diff function(please see in code) to highlight the difference but it says
 ValueError("style is not supported for non-unique indices.")

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv
import numpy as np

file1 = 'C:/Users/anagpurk/Desktop/backup/testoutput/test_act.csv'
file2 = 'C:/Users/anagpurk/Desktop/backup/testoutput/test_exp.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(file1,header=0,sep=r'\u0001', engine='python') 

df2 = pd.read_csv(file2,header=0,sep=r'\u0001', engine='python')

df_all = pd.concat([df.set_index('loop_vendor_id'), df2.set_index('loop_vendor_id')], 
                   axis='columns', keys=['First', 'Second'])

df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df.columns[1:]]


def highlight_diff(data, color='yellow'):
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    other = data.xs('First', axis='columns', level=-1)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other, level=0), attr, ''),
                        index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

df_final.style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=None)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/anagpurk/Desktop/backup/testoutput/output.xlsx', 
engine='xlsxwriter')
df_final.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet1',index=True)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Error message clearly says that your dataframe has duplicate index values. Use `reset_index`. Your current index will form another column in the data.